# Industrial Automation App with tightly integrated classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have written a Windows Forms app that interfaces with a variety of equipment to automate the testing of some gas sensors.  The program has four main objects, and sometimes these objects have to call methods or fetch properties from each other; a partial listing of the four relevant classes is below:

```
// GUI which creates the other class objects and displays their properties
// to the user.
public partial class FormCalibration : Form
{
    // Object to represent test equipment.
    private Equipment _equipment;

    // Object to represent devices under test.
    private List<Dut> _duts = new List<Dut>();

    // Object to represent tests.
    private Test _test;

    // When the user clicks a "Start" button, begin testing.
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create object for test equipment.
            _equipment = new Equipment(equipmentSettings);

            // Initialize the number of DUTs to configure the datalogger for.
            _equipment.DutInterface.Channels = new List<bool>(new bool[NumDuts]);

            // Create objects for devices under test.
            _duts.Clear();
            for (uint i = 0; i < NumDuts; i++)
            {
                Dut dut = new Dut(modelSetting)
                {
                    SetSerialNumber = SetDutSerialNumber,
                    SetStatus = SetDutStatus,
                };
                dut.DutInterface = _equipment.DutInterface;
                dut.Index = i + 1;
                dut.Selected = checkBox.Checked;
                dut.Status = DutStatus.Init;
                dut.SerialNumber = textBoxSerial.Text;
                dut.Message = string.Empty;
                _duts.Add(dut);
            }

            // Create object for the test itself.
            _test = new Test(testSetting, _equipment, _duts)
            {
                Finished = TestFinished,
                Update = TestUpdate
            };

            // Start the test.
            _test.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    public void TestFinished()
    {
        // Reset the form after a test is completed or cancelled
        // (omitted for brevity).
    }

    public void TestUpdate(int percent, string message)
    {
        // Update the form with the test's status and percent progress.
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = percent;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = message;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    // test equipment object
    private Equipment _equipment;

    // devices under test
    private readonly List<Dut> _duts;

    // Report test progress.
    public Action<int, string> Update;

    // Report test results.
    public Action Finished;

    public Test(TestSetting settings, Equipment equipment, List<Dut> duts)
    {
        // Save the reference to the equipment and DUTs objects.
        _equipment = equipment;
        _duts = duts;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Start a new test using a background worker thread
        // (omitted for brevity).
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Run action required as test progresses (i.e. update GUI).
        Update(e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState as string);
    }

    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the test was cancelled, update the GUI's status accordingly.
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Update(0, "Test cancelled.");
        }

        // Run actions required when test is completed (i.e. update GUI).
        Finished?.Invoke();
    }

    // This method handles all the testing of the DUTs.  Every time the
    // user presses "Start" this is what runs.
    private void TestThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Anything within this do-while structure can be cancelled.
            do
            {
                // Initialize test equipment.
                _testThread.ReportProgress(0, "Configuring test equipment...");
                _equipment.Open();
                if (_testThread.CancellationPending) { break; }

                // Initialize DUTs.
                _testThread.ReportProgress(0, "Configuring DUT Interface Device...");
                foreach (Dut dut in _duts)
                {
                    if (_testThread.CancellationPending) { break; }

                    dut.Open();
                }

                // Initialize DUT interface device.
                _equipment.DutInterface.Configure();

                // Perform test actions (omitted for brevity).
                ProcessTest();
            } while (false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }

        // Everything between here and the end of the test should be fast
        // and highly reliable since it cannot be cancelled.

        try
        {
            // Stop all controllers.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<VariableType, IControlDevice> c in _equipment.Controllers)
            {
                c.Value.SetControlMode(ControlMode.Ambient);
            }

            // Close DUTs.
            foreach (Dut dut in _duts)
            {
                dut.Close();
            }

            // Close test equipment.
            _testThread.ReportProgress(99, "Closing test equipment...");
            _equipment.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }

        // Update the GUI.
        _testThread.ReportProgress(100, "Done.");
        MessageBox.Show("Test complete.", "Notice");

        // If the operation was cancelled by the user, set the cancel property.
        if (_testThread.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; }
    }

    // This method is a good example of how Equipment and Dut classes are accessed in the Test class.
    private void ProcessSamples(double setpoint)
    {
        // Create an object to hold reference device readings.
        Dictionary<VariableType, double> referenceReadings = new Dictionary<VariableType, double>();

        // Add reference data to the dictionary.
        foreach (VariableType reference in _settings?.References ?? Enumerable.Empty<VariableType>())
        {
            double value = _equipment.References[reference].Readings[reference];

            referenceReadings.Add(reference, value);
        }

        // Record the data applicable to each DUT.
        foreach (Dut dut in _duts)
        {
            dut.Read(_elapsedTimeStopwatch.Elapsed, setpoint, referenceReadings[VariableType.GasConcentration]);

            if (_testThread.CancellationPending) { break; }
        }
    }
}

// Equipment class doesn't call the other classes, but contains properties
// that represent pieces of equipment, and are accessed by the Test object.
public class Equipment
{
    public Dictionary<VariableType, IControlDevice> Controllers;

    public Dictionary<VariableType, IReferenceDevice> References;

    public IDutInterfaceDevice DutInterface => _datalogger;

    public void Open()
    {
        // Initialize communication to each piece of equipment.
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        // Take a reading from each piece of equipment.
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        // Terminate communication with each piece of equipment.
    }
}

// Dut class doesn't call the other classes, but contains properties that
// represent features of a physical device under test, and are accessed by
// the Test object.
public class Dut
{
    // Set DUT status.
    public Action<uint, DutStatus> SetStatus;

    // Set DUT serial number.
    public Action<uint, string> SetSerialNumber;

    // Datalogger
    public IDutInterfaceDevice DutInterface { get; set; }

    // Data collected during a test.
    public List<TestResults> Results { get; set; } = new List<TestResults>();

    // DUT's fixture position or channel
    public uint Index { get; set; }

    // true if under test; false if idle
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    // DUT status (pass, fail, etc.)
    public DutStatus Status { get; set; }

    // DUT's unique identification number
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    // A message to be added to the log
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void Open()
    {
        // If the DUT has been enabled by the user...
        if (Selected)
        {
            // Configure DUT Interface device.
            DutInterface.Channels[(int)Index - 1] = Selected;

            // Set status to "Found".
            Status = DutStatus.Found;

            // Update GUI.
            SetStatus(Index, Status);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if ((Status == DutStatus.Found) ||
            (Status == DutStatus.Fail))
        {
            // Set status to Pass.
            Status = DutStatus.Pass;

            // Update GUI.
            SetStatus(Index, Status);

            // Save test results to csv file.
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(Results);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Read(TimeSpan elapsedTime, double setpoint, double reference)
    {
        // Only process found or failed DUTs.
        if ((Status == DutStatus.Found) ||
            (Status == DutStatus.Fail))
        {
            double reading = 0.0;

            reading = DutInterface.Readings[Index];

            // Save the result.
            Results.Add(new TestResults
            {
                ElapsedTime = elapsedTime,
                Setpoint = setpoint,
                Reference = reference,
                SensorValue = reading
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Instances of the four classes are passed to each other as parameters in the constructors.  The `Test` and `Dut` classes also have delegates that are assigned to the `FormCalibration` class in lieu of additional constructor parameters.  It all works fine, but I could have chosen to remove the constructor parameters and instead create more delegates.  Or remove the delegates in favor of adding more parameters to the constructors.

**What strategy would allow these classes to access methods or properties of the other classes and be easiest for a other developers to understand and maintain?**

The full project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/SensitTechnologies/TestSuite/tree/master/Sensit.App.Calibration).

Comment: Could you show us how these 4 classes call eachothers methods? I feel a visitor pattern will do the trick here.

Comment: @dfhwze, I'm at work and would appreciate more time to respond to your request.

Comment: I've edited the code listing in an attempt to show some clear examples of how the classes interact.  Please let me know if this is not adequate, @dfhwze.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It seems reviewable to me now. I'll have a go at it later this week.